# Run a batch on a different server

Tags: batch-file, remote-desktop

I have 2 batches: Launch & Target

- The **Launch.bat** is located in Server1
- The **Target.bat** is located in Server2

I'm in Server1 and I want to run **Target.bat** through using only **Launch.bat**

So here is what I have come by in **Launch.bat**:

```
wmic.exe /node:Server2 /user:myusername /password:"mypasseword" process call create "Targetlocalpath"
```

I have an error message when I run **Launch.bat**

> ERROR: Description= Access denied

Notice that I can access Server2 using the same credentials by a remote desktop connection

Is there anything I should change in my code?

Comment: Try and run it from the local path where the file exists on the remote device, as well as adding double quotes around the password. Something like similar to the following example `wmic.exe /node:Server2 /user:username /password:"mypassword" process call create "C:\Temp\batch.cmd"`

Comment: I added "wmic.exe" and the local path on Server2 for Target.bat ... But I still have the same error when I run Launch.bat

Comment: How about you use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54985077/edit) facility and update your question with the latest code/attempts, so that the pertinent information is in your question proper. Our membership does not generally read through all of the comments in order to determine if they can help, should the information be incomplete or out of date, it benefits nobody.

Comment: Good observation. Done